# Could not find manifest-merger.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.1.2) error after gradle 4.4 upgrade

Tags: android, gradle, compiler-errors

After updrading to gradle 4.4:

*gradle-wrapper.properties*

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Android project compilation fails with the following error:

```
Could not find manifest-merger.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.1.2).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/26.1.2/manifest-merger-26.1.2.jar
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The solution is quite simple, you have to invert `jcenter()` and `google()` repositories in your root *build.gradle* file (in mine `jcenter()` was first):

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Emphasis here on changing this in *both* places (in the `buildscript` section as well as `allprojects`) in the *root* build.gradle file, as that initially tripped me up. Most Android projects will have at least two build.gradle files, one in the root folder, and one in the `app` folder.

Comment: LOL, another page to the Android Studio jokebook

Answer (score 10):

I solved this by upgrading gradle wrapper version to `gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`

*gradle-wrapper.properties*

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

Comment: Work with me :D

Answer (score 4):

Cleaning up Gradle cache (~/.gradle/caches) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `.gradle` folder in your root repository
2. Update Gradle wrapper: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip`

in file: `gradle-wrapper.properties`

3. Sync Gradle again