# Could not find manifest-merger.jar

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest, manifest-merging

Could not find manifest-merger.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.1.0).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/26.1.0/manifest-merger-26.1.0.jar

Already tried the solution :[Could not find manifest-merger.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.1.2) error after gradle 4.4 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563783/could-not-find-manifest-merger-jar-com-android-tools-buildmanifest-merger26-1) but no success.

Can anyone plz help me out

My support libraries having same number of version

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
 implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
 implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
```

Comment: when you started facing this error ?

Comment: today, when i open my code.

Comment: @Umair, actually the code already developed 3 months ago

Comment: Well there should be something that you updated. Either it's android versions, gradle version etc.

Comment: Nope, nothing updated, just open the code

Comment: The answer on the previous question you've linked to *will* work, if you follow it correctly. See my note there. You may be changing the values in the wrong build.gradle file, or not in all places in the build.gradle file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

in my case change:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
```

TO:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google() //<--Google first
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
```

it works. wtf!

Comment: Man, you just saved my day, this was freaking me out

Answer (score 1):

Work for me:

1. close project (!)
2. gradle-wrapper.properties:

> ```
> distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
> ```

3. build.gradle:

> ```
> dependencies {
>     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
> }
> ```

4. google() above:

> ```
> repositories {
>     google()
>     jcenter()
> }
> ```

5. open project and sync